# Enable wheel zoom on embedded plotly chart

Tags: python, iframe, plotly, plotly-python

I would like to embed a chart exported to chart studio, and be able to use mouse wheel to zoom in the chart (which is the most convenient way when it comes to maps).

However, no matter which option I use when I export my chart (iframe, html), once it's embedded in another website, wheel-zoom is disabled. I used jupyter-lab and it was enabled. Is there anything I'm missing on ?

Here are some examples of the result I would like to get

https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/

Embedding using iframe :

```html
<iframe width="900" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//plotly.com/~hugolmn/3.embed"></iframe>
```

**Edit for more details**

Here is the code I used to export the graph to chart studio.

```py
# Exporting to chart_studio
py.plot(fig, filename = 'sncf-train-stations', auto_open=True)
```

[Here](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/~hugolmn/3/#/) is the uploaded graph and [here](https://hugolmn.github.io/2020/06/17/sncf-train-station-attendance.html) is where it's embedded.

On Chart Studio the mouse wheel zoom works well, but not when it's integrated elsewhere.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you try setting [`'scrollZoom': True`](https://plotly.com/python/configuration-options/#enabling-scroll-zoom)?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately I already tried and it doesn't work. I don't think fig.show() actually adds anything to the figure object. So once it's online, this config option is probably not there anymore. I added more details to my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use [`write_html`](https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/#saving-to-an-html-file) to create your figure in html and then use this as the source for your iframe.  So something like:

```
fig.write_html("map.html")
```

and then an iframe like:

```
<iframe width="900" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="map.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: I wish there was a solution using Chart Studio directly, but this works fine! Thanks !